# What are the boundaries of the entropy of a gaussian random variable? What is their meaning?

Tags: information-theory, entropy, gaussian

Given a gaussian random variable $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with p.d.f.:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\cdot e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$

Then we can calculate its entropy (expected value of information) as:
$$
H(X)=-\int{f(x)log_a{f(x)}dx}\\
=-\int{f(x)log_a\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\cdot e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)dx}\\
=-\int{f(x)\left(log_a(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2}-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}log_ae\right)dx}\\
=\frac{1}{2}log_a(2\pi\sigma^2)\underbrace{\int{f(x)dx}}_{=1}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}log_ae\underbrace{\int{(x-\mu)^2f(x)}}_{=E[(X-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2}\\
=\frac{1}{2}log_a(2\pi e\sigma^2)
$$

Given the relationship of $H(X)$ with $\sigma^2$ I was told that, as intuition suggests, when the variance decreases and $f(x)$ becomes a bell tighter around its mean $\mu$, uncertainty about the value of $X$ becomes less, thus also entropy reduces.

However, I don't fully understand this consideration at the boundaries: why does it look like entropy $H(X)=0$ when $\sigma^2=1/2\pi e$? And why below this limit it looks like entropy increases in negative sign even if the variance is decreasing towards 0? If these are correct results, what is their meaning?

Comment: you are considering the _differential_ entropy, which can become negative, as discussed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Differential_entropy

Comment: Yeah I meant that... Sorry if the notation is confusing. However I'm still wondering if the differential entropy on this interval of low variance has some kind of intuitive meaning or it's just the result of the continuous extension of entropy.

Comment: negative differential entropy has no meaning, it's not invariant under a change of variables, there is nothing special about negative or zero value.